# On offset commit Kafka is not aware of partition but no rebalancing took place

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Processes of mine consume records by wildcard subscription; I cache partition information of the received records to do offset commits (manually) periodically;

In generall I have several KafkaConsumer with the same group.id and I use the `RoundRobinAssignor` to distribute topics/partitions equally between my processes.

During offset commit I receive the following exception:

> Offset commit failed on partition FooBar at offset
>   36402: The coordinator is not aware of this member.

I only commit offsets that I know because I received a record via this topic. I can see no invocation of the `Rebalancer.onPartitionsRevoked|onPartitionsAssigned` methods which I registered during topic subscription. I do topic subscription like this:

```
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Pattern.compile('<myPattern>'),
            new MyRebalanceListener());
```

I do not understand why the `RebalanceListern` methods are not called? As I understood only rebalancing could lead to the situation where my KafkaConsumer is not aware of a topic anymore (which let the  topic offset commit fail in this case).

Do you have any ideas?

---

Added information based on question in comments below:

I use the default KafkaConsumerConfig settings except

```
custom:
max.poll.records=100
auto.offset.reset=earliest
enable.auto.commit=false

defaults:
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
session.timeout.ms=10000
max.poll.interval.ms=300000
```

The Rebalancer class looks like this

```java
    public class DataTransferJobRebalanceListener implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(final Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            LOGGER.info("rebalancing of topics occured; handling onPartitionsRevoked...");
            commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(final Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            // NOOP - nothing to do if new partitions are assigned
        }
    }
```

In the `commit` method I commit cached data to a database and also commit the Kafka offsets via `kafkaConsumer.commitSync(partitionOffsets);`.

The  variable is a map with topic partitions and offsets of the records that were received after the last commit. I clear the list after each commit. 
It can take some seconds to process the records which were received in a poll but should not take more than `max.poll.interval.ms` but I will check this...

Comment: Can you post the code in your `MyRebalanceListener` class?

Comment: what values are you using for session.timeout.ms, heartbeat.interval.ms and max.poll.interval.ms ? also, how long does it actually take you to process the results of a single poll() call?

Comment: @mjuarez added the RebalanceListener code

Comment: @radai added the config settings

Comment: im still betting the broker times you out over session.timeout.ms. at 10 seconds it could even be a long GC pause, but i'd start by measuring how long you take between calls to poll() and commit

Comment: @radai I guess you are right; I enabled kafka logging and miss some expected heartbeat responses; Now I wonder who is responsible for sending the heartbeats and at what interval does this happen - and how is it related to the polls and the processing time between the polls - or simple what can cause a heartbeat delay so `heartbeat.interval.ms` is not reached?

Comment: there's a background thread on the consumer that sends heartbeats. your setup allows for 10 seconds of no heartbeating (which i think was breached). i dont remember specifics but i've seen cases where GC caused this or lock contention between the background thread and the user thread calling poll.

Comment: @raid That (disconnected from the broker because of missing heartbeats because of somehow blocked heartbeat background thread) is probably the root cause of my problem. If you add that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.